# Java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

i have a prepared statement in which i set a field as :

```
busStatement.setDouble(5,bus.getFare());
```

my get Fare Function is :

```
public double getFare() {
        return fare;
    }
```

the fare is being set via commandform , fare in commandform is of string type

```
bus.setFare(Double.valueOf(addBusCommandForm.getFare()));
```

**The fare column in the DB is ::: Fare NUMBER(7,2)**

now when i do this :

`busStatement.executeUpdate();`

It gives me

```
ava.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Now i am not able to comprehend where i went wrong ?

Comment: It could be one of the other five parameters you put. Post more code.

Comment: @DiogoSantana It was Working fine with all the other code, the only change that i have made is in this. is it required ?

Comment: The message is pretty straightforward... my guess it you should be passing some string to a NUMBER field.

Comment: @Subham Maybe there is an issue with your SQL statement. Could you show it ?

Comment: Showing the statement and the other parameters would *at least* let other eyes verify that you didn't do something trivial like get the parameter indexes wrong when you added the new one; but might also reveal something more subtle. If there is nothing obviously wrong in what you have showed, then it is probably in something you have not.